# Apparmor denied Gnome monitor

Tags: gnome, permissions

I've been with a Dell XPS 13 with native Ubuntu for half a month and today I've realized that I have some Gigabytes of this line. Basically I had the Gnome monitor open some days and it was logging this line probably more than 20 times per second while open.

It should be a permissions problem, but I haven't done any heavy customization of the laptop, and this is just the Gnome Monitor, a quite usual application from Gnome itself (I think). So I really think it should just be perfectly configured from the beginning.

```
AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/run/systemd/sessions/8" pid=8445 comm="gnome-system-mo"
```

Anyone has any idea of what can I do for stopping this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a current known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor/+bug/1791454

Closing this